# Многократный Сократ

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, знаки

Смотрю описание знака [Сократ](/help/badges/89/socratic):

> Задавайте интересные вопросы в течение 100 дней и поддерживайте положительный баланс голосов. *Знак можно получать многократно*

То же самое [на английском](//stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4129/socratic):

> Ask a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintain a positive question record. *This badge can be awarded multiple times.*

При этом в аналогичных знаках [Любознательный](/help/badges/87/curious) и [Пытливый ум](/help/badges/88/inquisitive) такой приписки нет.

Действительно ли Сократа можно получать многократно? Если да, то, во-первых, чем он отличается от двух подобных знаков, а во-вторых, за что он будет даваться повторно? Вряд ли же с каждым хорошим вопросом после сотого будет капать по ещё одному Сократу. Сброс всех счётчиков и отсчёт новых ста дней? Что-то не похоже на то, как устроены знаки...

Comment: Однократ, Двукрат, Трёхкрат.

Comment: Кстати, у тебя уже тройной Сократ здесь на Мете!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ага, 1/3 всех сократов на мете)))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, Сократа можно получить многократно.

На enSO [есть пользователи с 5-ю Сократами](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/438497), например [Ian Boyd](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4129/socratic?userid=12597).

Судя по всему, второго Сократа дают за вопросы в течение 200 разных дней, третьего - за вопросы в течение 300 разных дней, и т.д.

При этом вполне логично, что Любознательный дается всего один раз, иначе вместе с первым Сократом участник получал бы двадцатого Любознательного.